# How to push object to existing array in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

In the below code I have a value and that is an object how to can I push to the exist array.

```
methods: {
  onChange(event) {
    this.newItems.push(event.target.value);
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
}
```

and my blade is:

```html
<select @change='onChange($event)' class="form-control">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option>
  <option v-for='item,key in items' :value="item">@{{ item.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Make sure you already decalred 'var this.newItems = [];', before pushing new object to array

Comment: I declared that array.

Comment: Please add what error log you are getting?

Comment: "newItems" => array:1 [
    0 => "[object Object]"
  ]. my object is wrong saved in array

Comment: So you got this? Also, you `v-for` is for `items` while in the code you refer to `this.newItems`, is it on purpose?

Comment: Did you get the fix  @SayedSajadHosseini?

Comment: @moshFeu when I want to display my object on blade I see the correct value but I went to save to the array.

Comment: @sarvesh Not yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using v-model on the select to detect which is currently selected.

```
<div id="app">
  <select @change="onChange" class="form-control" v-model="selected">
   <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option>
   <option v-for='item,key in items' :value="item">@{{ item.name }}
   </option>
</select>
<p v-for="newItem in newItems">
  {{newItem}}
</p>
</div>
```

and then push this.selected in your onChange method instead:

```
this.newItems.push(this.selected)
```

Hope this helps.

Working fiddle of your code with some small modifications:

https://jsfiddle.net/MapletoneMartin/e4oth98p/7/